# How to type UTF-8 characters in Windows 7 Command Prompt

Tags: utf-8, cmd

How can I type in Persian (UTF-8) in Windows 7 Command Prompt?

As this question claims
[Unicode characters in Windows command line - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how/388500#388500)

I used `chcp 65001` and changed the console font to `Lucida` but the result is some rectangular characters when I type in Persian.

Its interesting as I copy these characters and paste them in a editor they are in Persian alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

I just select `Courier New` font, I see Persian chars, but see left to right instead of right to left!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

CMD.exe is ASCII (not ANSI like older Windows programs). Writing unicode to it just does character conversions. CMD can be started in unicode mode. Type `cmd /?`.

Comment: it says use CMD /U, but the result is the same (some rectangular characters). Its interesting as I copy these characters and paste them in a editor they are in Persian alphabet.

Comment: That means they are correct, but the font doesn't have the character. Try different fonts. Can you copy in both ascii (OEM/DOS)and unicode?

Comment: I don't see Persian as a range in the cmd unicode font (Lucinda Console). Is there another name for Persian (an ancient greek word for Iranian) that could be used. There is no Iranian. Does Iran use a particular alphabet (English speaking countries use Western). What is the name of one of the Iranian characters (so I can search for it). There was no Parthia code range either (Latin).

Comment: Nowadays, Persian use Arabic script plus some extra characters, but I think it has its own range named Persian or Farsi or Parsi (Farsi is the local pronunciation), By the way there is just three font I can choose and none of them works for Persian

Comment: Is your computer set up for Arabic in Regional Settings, especially the non unicode setting. These are the sub ranges in charmap. 10112,  "Box Drawings"
10113,  "Block Elements & Geometric Shapes"
10114,  "Symbols & Dingbats"
10115,  "Spacing Modifier Letters"
10116,  "Combining Diacritical Marks"
10117,  "Greek"
10118,  "Cyrillic"
10119,  "Armenian"
10120,  "Hebrew"
10121,  "Arabic"
10122,  "Devanagari"
10123,  "Bengali"
10124,  "Gurmukhi"
10125,  "Gujarati"
10126,  "Oriya"
10127,  "Tamil"
}

Comment: For non unicode setting in the Regional Settings it has been set up for Persian. I remember Lucida Bold Unicode supports Persian as a unicode range. I don't know much about the ranges you offered and how to apply them

Comment: The ranges are just the catagories Character map shows. They are hard coded. If using that font, and your characters are in it, and (maybe) you are in unicode, it should show. My specialicity is European characters for English computers. Non European non unicode characters always used a different mechanism to European characters. That means I can't help further. But if you can copy it, it exists.

Comment: Thank you very much for your consideration, In my case to use Python shell for Persian I found other tools such DreamPie.